# Setting up Sharepoint 2010/2013 Dev environment on a 2GB RAM machine

Tags: 2010, 2013

I have a task in which I need to provide synchronization between MailChimp and Sharepoint Mail List and Contacts.

I only have a 2GM RAM Machine running Windows 7 on Core 2 Dou based processor. Is it possible to run Sharepoint for development purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that setup, forget about running 2013.

It will be possible to run a 2010, but with a minimum of service applications. I still think you will have a very bad experience though.

In my testing, 4GB of RAM is what you should use as minimum for 2010, and up around 10GB for 2013, to have a some what good experience and response.

Comment: I agree with that, the minimum that I've used is installing SharePoint 2010 Standalone in a Windows 7 environment with 4 gb of RAM. Less than that sounds like tough, mostly because you need SQL as well...